# how to process sweeping surface whose section curve is a polygon?

Tags: polygon, nurbs

I've got stumped by a question,recently.Now, I have a polygon and a NURBS Curve,then I want to make a sweeping surface that the NURBS Curve as a trojectory curve and the polygon as a section curve. Problem is the polygon can be triangle or quadrangle or others, that is it has N sides(N>=3).And a point on the NURBS curve is the circumcenter of a certain polygon. In order to do sweeping,I need to make a NURBS presentation for every polygon. If so, the workload is huge as the sides of polygon is undefined and the radius is also undefined. Have any good solutions?

Comment: What nurbs functions do you have already?  Do you have degree elevation?  Do you already have a sweep function that takes a nurbs curve as the section curve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,dear tfinniga.Now,I have NURBS representation for curve in v direction which is socalled trajectory curve and the section curve is a regular polygon.What I know to the section curve is its radius,its sides and its circumcentre which is certain point in trajectory curve. Then, I want to get a NURBS representation for the swept surface.Do you have any suggests?